# Какой вид кода лучше?

Tags: jquery

Значит есть такой код:

```
$('.loadComm div').live('click', function() {
    loadComment($(this));
});

function loadComment($loadBut){
    // Здесь идёт обработка клика по объекту
    // ajax, отработка полученного ответа, его обработка и т.д.
}
```

или лучше такой вариант:

```
$('.loadComm div').live('click', function() {
    // Здесь идёт обработка клика по объекту
    // ajax, отработка полученного ответа, его обработка и т.д.
}
```

И если можно, то почему (в двух словах)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если функция более 3-х строк то лучше использовать именованный вариант, к тому же можно делать просто:

```
function loadComment(){
    // Здесь идёт обработка клика по объекту
    // ajax, отработка полученного ответа, его обработка и т.д.
    $(this)... // контекст будет сохранятся
}

$(document).on('click', '.loadComm div', loadComment);
```

используёте [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), т.к. [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) deprecated

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated

Comment: Всё понял. Функция разумеется более 3-х строк. Переделаю сейчас все подобные моменты. Не понял строку 

    $(this)... // контекст будет сохранятся

Comment: вам не обязательно передавать ссылку на `this` как параметр функции, обработчик клика будет вызван в контексте кликнутого элемента, т.о. `this` функции будет указывать на него, что-то вроди:

    loadComment.apply(clickElement, []);

Comment: Всё понял, спасибо. Ответ принят, сообщение отмеченно.

Comment: Не понял немного, а в чем выгода в данном случае? Зачем разбивать 1 обработчик на вызов функции и саму функцию? Если целостно все - то и читается целостно.  А если разнесено по кускам, то появляется необходимость отдельно искать обработчик событий, смотреть какая функция и затем искать саму функцию. Даже если там 20 строк кода...

Comment: если нормально именовать функции, то по одному названию станет ясно, что функция делает, а если его(имени) нет, то через N часов/дней/месяцев вы будете с невразумительным выражением лица всматриваться в функцию пытаясь понять, что же происходит по клику на тот или иной элемент. А вообще я за такой подход [delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы говорил не о N строках, а об уникальности.

Если функция используется или может использоваться в разных местах — очевидно, что разумно дать ей имя.

Если она только для одного вот этого конкретного места, и в других совершенно неприменима — я бы сказал, что имя ей ни за чем не нужно, даже если она далеко не однострочник. Любой, посмотревший на код уже увидит `$(element).on(event)`, и повторное `onElementEvent`, в общем-то, избыточно.

Comment: ну, дык, к этому и надо стремится - чтобы функция использовалась или могла быть использована многократно, повторное использование кода или DRY - один из основных принципов написания качественных программ

Comment: Функция используется многократно. И в разных местах, в зависимости от переданных параметров.